# Python function that returns values from list smaller than a number

Tags: python

My function needs to take in a list of integers and a certain integer and return the numbers in the list that are smaller than the specific integer. Any advice?

```
def smallerThanN(intList,intN):
    y=0
    newlist=[]
    list1=intList
    for x in intList:
        if int(x)  < int(intN):
            print(intN)
            y+=1
            newlist.append(x)
    return newlist
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a list comprehension with an "if" filter to extract those values in the list less than the specified value:

```
def smaller_than(sequence, value):
    return [item for item in sequence if item < value]
```

I recommend giving the variables more generic names because this code will work for *any* sequence regardless of the type of sequence's items (provided of course that comparisons are valid for the type in question).

```
>>> smaller_than([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 5)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> smaller_than('abcdefg', 'd')
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> smaller_than(set([1.34, 33.12, 1.0, 11.72, 10]), 10)
[1.0, 1.34]
```

N.B. There is already a similar answer, however, I'd prefer to declare a function instead of binding a lambda expression.

Comment: *There is already a similar answer* Indeed, but you've taken it much further along with explanation and style guide. Cheers :).

Comment: How can I make it in a way that the commas won't be considered as individual values?

Comment: @Helen: which commas? Are you are passing a comma separated string to your function? If so then you can split the string (e.g. `s = '1,2,3,4,5'`) into a list of integers with [int(x) for x in s.split(',')] before calling `smaller_than()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
integers_list = [4, 6, 1, 99, 45, 76, 12]

smallerThan = lambda x,y: [i for i in x if i<y]

print smallerThan(integers_list, 12)
```

Output:

> [4, 6, 1]

Answer (score -1):

```
def smallerThanN(intList, intN):
    return [x for x in intList if x < intN]

>>> smallerThanN([1, 4, 10, 2, 7], 5)
[1, 4, 2]
```