# it is give none but ı think the algoritm is true where is the mistake could you tell me?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def listUnder(inList,bound):
a=[]
a.append(inList)
b=[]
b.append(bound)
for i in a:
if i<b:
return i
print(listUnder([34,10,9,5,44,1],10))
```

Write a function listUnder(inList, bound) which takes two input argumens inlist(list of integers) and bound (int) and returns a list that consists of all elements in inlist that are strictly smaller than bound  in the same order they appear in inlist.

output:
print(listUnder([34, 10, 9, 5, 44, 1],10))
[9, 5, 1]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python function that returns values from list smaller than a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33470169/python-function-that-returns-values-from-list-smaller-than-a-number)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are doing this in a complicated manner, a simple list comp would do the job here:

```
def listUnder(inList, bound):
    return [i for i in inList if i < bound]
```

Aside from that, appending your input list to a list inside your function results in a nested list, which is probably the source of your error. Also, you return a single list element in your for-loop, how can you expect getting a list?

Comment: thank you very much well you think why my code did not work because I think despite the fact that it is long it was true.